# Problem during deploy a smart contract from an other

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, hardhat-deploy

i have a question about give permission to one smart contract to be deployed only from an other.

I have deployed my first smart contract on mumbai testnet from my hardhat local environment. I have copied the address of the smart contract deployed and paste inside a modifier of second contract to check if is the factory contract that create it.

This is the code of second smart contract:

```
contract B {
    address _addressFactory = addressCopiedFromMumbaiTestnet;
    uint256 datecreation;
    ....

    modifier onlyFactory() {
        require(msg.sender == _addressFactory, "Not permitted - not Factory");
        _;
    }

    constructor (address owner) onlyFactory{
        _owner = owner;
        datecreation = block.timestamp;
    }
    ....
}
```

What is wrong? I don't understand what is the problem

EDIT 1:
I tried to edit the address with my account address, and only i can deploy this smart contract. I think is a problem with my first deployed smart contract.

You could check it here: https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x78d490694344e80eceb82c64008cf940d0cf25ef

Comment: What's the problem? The `onlyFactory` modifier will only allow the factory contract to deploy contract B. How is the factory deploying contract B? Having a modifier in the constructor seems an unnecessary problem. If only the factory contract could deploy it then the factory should be the one enforcing the rules.

Comment: @Ismael the problem, is that don't work. I can't use the address of the factory contract that is deployed to testnet with file in same folder of the project. I don't know why, but when i will write the address on the second contract, also the second will create a runtime from the first, the first will be recompiled. it will do error.. You can see there: https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x0a4ab050b7a5213caa2147b619c03881e1415743

Comment: @Ismael Now i found this solution: create a stupid method on Factory Smart contract that will return true, if an Object from address, is type of contract A:

inside A:
function iAmAFactory()public pure returns(bool isIndeed) {
        return true;
    }

Inside contract B:
modifier onlyFactory() {
        require(A(msg.sender).iAmAFactory(), "Not permitted - not Factory");
        _;
    }

Comment: @Ismael but in this way, Every A type could deploy and interact with all B contract.
I need deploy A one type, and only first A could create B objects and interact with them. I need only keep private the smart contract of A to not deploy any others A type?

Comment: I don't understand why you need `onlyFactory`. To me it seems you are trying to implement  OpenZeppelin's Owned but backwards. Can you explain in simply words what's the purpose and relationship between the contracts?

Comment: @Ismael where i can show you the code to explain better the problem and my solution? GitHub repo?

Comment: You can edit the question to add all the details there.